# php/html tables, identical, displaying in different sizes in same jqm container

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, html-table

I have four identical html tables, made using PHP, displayed in a jQuery mobile container. The tables draw from a common stylesheet `customstyles.css`.

I have menus that allow the user to switch between the four tables. So, for example, the user selects table1, then table3, then back to table1. Each table is a different PHP file.

However, the tables display  in different sizes. I have compared them in Meld, and cannot see any differences in their common markup.

Here's the structure each of them follows:

```
<?php

      {//php code: query, results processed in while loop}

/////////// format, make, and populate table 1 /////////////
$tablevar = '';
$tablevar .="//jquery mobile stylesheets, customstyles.css, opening <page div>, <content div>//
$tablevar .= "<table class='common-tables'>";
$tablevar .= "<caption >$caption_variable</caption>";
$tablevar .= "<thead><TR>
<TH align ='left' >HeadA</TH>
<TH align ='left'>HeadB</TH>

</TR></thead>";
$tablevar .= "

<TR>
<TH>Type1</th>
<TD>{$variable}</TD>
<TD>{$variable1}</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TH>Type2</TH>
<TD>{$variable2}</TD>
<TD>{$variable3}</TD>
</TR>";


$tablevar .= "</TABLE>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role='footer'>
        <h4>footer text</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>";
} //end of while loop
echo "$tablevar";
?>
```

Everything on the page outside the tables is identical -- jqm icons, menus, etc. They are all the same exact size. But two of the tables display "bigger" than the other two.

I can't figure this out. Is this a common issue? I have never encountered it before. Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "bigger" displays had a php notice at the top, prior to the `<!DOCTYPE html>` -- I should have read Meld more carefully. I fixed the underlying php issue, and now the tables display exactly the same.

I don't know why that should affect it, but the moral of the story is don't have php notices/warnings in the first place.